# Enviar por QueryString valores enteros

Tags: c#

Estoy leyendo los datos de una base y trato de enviarlos a una api, el primer y tercer parametros son del tipo entero, pero al tratar de enviarlos como GetInt tengo el error que no puede convertir un string en int, como puedo pasarle un entero a queryString.

```
 if (reader.HasRows)
         {
            while (reader.Read())
                {

string url = "https:xxxxxxx"; 

WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.QueryString.Add("OperacionID", reader.GetInt32(0)); //43
wc.QueryString.Add("Referencia", reader.GetString(1));
wc.QueryString.Add("Estado", reader.GetInt32(2));//262
wc.QueryString.Add("Duracion", 0);


var data = wc.UploadValues(url, "POST", wc.QueryString);
responseString = UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

          }
       }
```

Gracias

Comment: el reader de que tipo es? si los lee como string, porque no los tomas como string y despues los transformas a entero?

Comment: Lo que dice gbianchi es lo que debes hacer, porque como su nombre lo dice es un "querySTRING"

Answer (score 2):

La propiedad [`QueryString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.querystring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebClient_QueryString), es una propiedad de tipo [`NameValueCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=netframework-4.7.2), que:

> Representa una colección de claves de String y valores String asociados a los que se puede obtener acceso con la clave o con el índice.

Como ahí se dice, los valores deben ser de tipo `string`, no pueden ser enteros (al fin y al cabo, es un query**string**). Así que debes añadir los valores con ese tipo:

```
wc.QueryString.Add("OperacionID", reader.GetInt32(0).ToString()); //43
wc.QueryString.Add("Referencia", reader.GetString(1));
wc.QueryString.Add("Estado", reader.GetInt32(2).ToString());//262
wc.QueryString.Add("Duracion", "0");
```

Comment: Al ejecucutarlo con ToString() tengo el siguiente error La conversión especificada no es válida.

Comment: A ver si nos ponemos las pilas en la cola de sugerencias eh... :-P https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEnuB.png

Comment: @fedorqui vaya...me has adelantado, habrá que darle caña ;)